# VS 2010 changing anchor property when opening or running project

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I was a little confused to see the 'changed' asterisks showing up in on of my form tabs upon opening my project. I then ran the project and found that button whose anchor property I had set to Bottom | Right had been changed to Bottom | Left. I changed it back in both the IDE and in the .designer file but the ide keeps changing it back.

Anyone else ever run into this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I guess the lesson here is never leave both the .designer file and the Form View open at the same time when you close your project. Apparently it will sometimes 'confuse' the IDE.

I closed both files then closed and reopened the project and things seem normal.